# Can't Use Quad Remesh On Some Objects

Tags: python, add-on, remesh, octane-render-engine

Using: BlenderOctane (2.93.0, the latest I believe)
Specs: RTX 3090, Ryzen 3600, 32 GB RAM, Win 10

Problem: When I try to use the Quad Remesh addon in ***non***-Octane blender in the provided file, I can remesh the door. When I try to remesh it in the Octane version of blender I get the error in the attached image. Tried a fresh download of BlenderOctane, reloading scripts, reloading Quad Remesher, rebooting PC, and praying to my ancestor's God. None have worked, any ideas as to why I cannot use Quad Remesher on some objects in BlenderOctane?

Link To Problem Example:https://drive.google.com/file/d/15b6ibi4Hh-L5IIB4qwb7WYvomfm_bDLe/view?usp=sharing

***!!PROBLEM SOLVED!!***: Had to remove all materials from the object and then I could remesh and then apply materials.
Lesson learned, do all remeshing before applying any materials or textures.

[image: Error When Remesh Button Pressed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try settings the material output node to eevee/cycles/all when you do the remesh. currently it's "none" for non-octane blender.

[image]

Comment: Thank you but sadly no joy. Tried All, Eevee, and Cycles but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I had to remove the material all together from the mesh and then I could do it. I also noticed that if I remesh an object that has a material on it (and it lets me do it), the material is changed to a new default one. Is this expected behavior?